# When I tried to deploy to Heroku my Django project it is not detecting the buildpack. Could anyone help me please?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have tried all methods in the documentation but still I am having the same issue.

[image: I am pushing it to Heroku with several methods but still I have the same issue]

Comment: Do you have a `setup.py` or `requirements.txt` in the root of the repo per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#recognizing-a-python-app?

Comment: yes I have created it with pip freeze > requirements.txt

Comment: The one we see in the screenshot (please don't post screenshots of text content) is not at the *root* of the repo.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. You need to add a `Procfile` at the root of your project with content such as

   ```
   web: gunicorn yourproject.wsgi --log-file--
   ```
2. You also need to specify the runtime python version to use.

   You do that by creating
   `runtime.txt` at the root your project with content
   `python-3.7.9`
3. If you didn't create one before, we need to create a `requirements.txt` file to tell Heroku what Python packages need to be installed on our server.

Comment: I have created it already before deploying it to the heroku do I have to do it again?

Comment: Is it at the root of your project? @Agabyok?

Comment: I do not know but as you said I have created runtime.txt but now it is finding an error from runtime and saying " Push rejected, failed to compile Python app."

Comment: yes I have navigated and it started deployment but now it is showing  Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1

Comment: Ensure it's an ```-``` between python and the version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228403/discussion-between-agabyok-and-dennohpeter).

Answer (score 0):

`No default language could be detected for this app.`

You need to specify a buildpack. It can't pick a default language because you are either missing files (e.g. `requirements.txt`) **or** you have too many like `Aptfile`, `Gemfile`, `package,json`, etc.
So if you have `requirements.txt` and `package.json` it does not know if your project uses python or node or even both.

Here I am using multiple buildpacks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz5Vd.png

Add the buildpacks either through [CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#setting-a-buildpack-on-an-application) or through the [dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvYnm.png).

Answer (score 0):

did you make necessary changes in your settings.py ,created Procfile, and all requirmenets packages in requirements.txt by

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

if not please check this link
[heroku django configure](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration)

please share your settings.py file by copying code not as screenshot
what i can see it says no default language detected make sure that there is default language in your settings.py in language code

Comment: Yes I have did all configurations but still the same thing I have deployed it but it is showing me an application error with 503 status

Comment: share your settings.py